# Facebook Graph-api, premissions for Shares count (Invalid OAuth access token signature)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am far from the programming and PHP, but got the challenge to get the Fb share count for the website :)

I'm trying to get the proper App Access Token and send the request to Fb
according to [this article](http://www.phpbuilder.com/articles/application-architecture/design/counting-facebook-likes-and-twitter-tweets-your-app.html).

The request should be like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.myurl.com/my-page&access_token=myappid|myappsecret

And I getting this error.

```
   {
       "error": {
          "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "code": 190,
          "fbtrace_id": "FfZKAkCyad1"
       }
    }
```

I am going to use it in PHP roughly like this:

```
function facebook_count($url)
{
$results = @file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $url .'&access_token=myappid|myappsecret');
if ($results) {
$like_array = json_decode($results, true);
if (!empty($like_array['shares']))
return ($like_array['shares']);
}

return 0;
}
```

My guess, I checked wrong Permissions (scopes) for my App token. Did not found an answer in FB dev page. Checked this for now:

> user_likes, read_insights, read_audience_network_insights, public_profile

**What Scope do I need to check, if I need only the shares count by the link?**

Or in what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an **App Access Token**... So the actual permissions (referring to **User Access Tokens**!) are irrelevant.

So, hopefully you are replacing `myappid|myappsecret` with your actual App Id and App Secret. If ynot, there's your error. Furthermore, I think in the `file_get_contents` call then `?id=` part in the URL is missing.